# Convolution doubt

Tags: calculus, convolution

Can someone explain why the general formula of the convolution is this one:

$$(f*g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-\tau)g(\tau) \, d\tau$$

But when both $f(\tau)$ and $g(\tau)$ are equal to zero for negative values of $\tau$, the convolution turns into:

$$(f*g)(t)=\int_0^t f(t-\tau)g(\tau) \, d\tau$$

I always thought that it would be more logical that it would become:

$$(f*g)(t)=\int_0^\infty f(t-\tau)g(\tau) \, d\tau$$

Comment: It's all the same, the integrand $f(t-\tau)g(\tau)$ is zero for $\tau < 0$ or $\tau > t$. Just convention.

Comment: Yes, at first it becomes like what you write at the end, but note that $f(t-\tau)$ is $0$ in the range $(t,\infty)$.

Comment: Ignore my answer, I mixed up what you wrote!

Comment: where is $g$ on the RHS of last equation?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Thanks for noticing the mistake. I already correct it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just notice that for $\tau<0$ you have $g(\tau)=0$ while for $\tau>t$ you have $f(t-\tau)=0$. In both cases $f(t-\tau)g(\tau) = 0$.
Hence 
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t-\tau)g(\tau)\, d\tau
 = \int_0^t f(t-\tau)g(\tau)\, d\tau.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Actually this is so simple that I am felling kind of dumb for not noticing it before.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use indicator functions for these kind of problems.

Write $f(t)$ as $f(t)1_{\{t \geq 0\}}$ and $g(t)$ as $g(t)1_{\{t \geq 0\}}$. Then the integrand becomes
$$ f(t-\tau)g(\tau)1_{\{\tau \leq t,\tau\geq 0\} } = f(t-\tau)g(\tau)1_{\{0 \leq \tau \leq t\} }$$

$\blacksquare$