# Why doesn't convolution work for i.i.d. $\chi^2(1)$ random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

It's a well known result shown with the equality of the moment generating functions that if random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and identically distributed $\chi^2(1)$ random variables, then $Y = X_1 + X_2$ is distributed according to a $\chi^2(2)$.

When I tried to show this result with convolution, I did not arrive at the same answer:

With the given distributions, the probability density functions (pdfs) of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $f_{x_{1}}(x) = \frac{e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2\, \pi \,x}}$ and $f_{x_{2}}(x) = \frac{e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2\, \pi \,x}}$, respectfully, with $0 <x< \infty$.

Then the pdf of $Y = X_1 + X_2$ is the convolution of the pdfs of $X_1$ and $X_2$:

$$
\begin{align*}
f_y(t) =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{x_1}(x) \; f_{x_2}(t - x) \; dx \\
=& - \frac{e^{-t/2}}{\pi} \cdot \arctan\left( \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{t - x}} \right) \bigg|_{0}^{\infty}
\end{align*}
$$

But $\lim_{x \to \infty} \, \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{t - x}} = \sqrt{-1} = i$

What am I missing, or where am I going wrong?

Comment: The integral defining the convolution is on the interval (0,x), not on (-oo,+oo).

Comment: Ahhhh (I think you mean (0, t) in this case), makes sense. Here's a question showing what you mean: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450402/convolution-doubt , I'll accept an answer if you create one

Comment: Yes, (0,t), sorry about the typo.